# what will happen when .aof file will be very large?

Tags: redis

I am using Redis 2.8.4. Enabled append only in configuration. It is working fine as per my requirement but the prob is this file will be getting more larger so it may create memory shortage in future? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis has a way to compress the aof file by removing useless operations.

> For example, if you are incrementing a counter 100 times, you'll end
>   up with a single key in your dataset containing the final value, but
>   100 entries in your AOF. 99 of those entries are not needed to rebuild
>   the current state.

It is a automatic job in  Redis 2.8.4, see redis.conf for `auto-aof-rewrite-percentage` and `auto-aof-rewrite-min-size`. You can also start it with `BGREWRITEAOF` command, see https://redis.io/commands/bgrewriteaof.